# Weird font displayed on websites

Tags: windows-7, browser, fonts, web

I am running Windows 7 on a Dell XPS M1640

I have downloaded and installed a lot of fonts recently and I think this is were my problem began. I started to notice that some (not all) websites would display some of its text (links, tabs, titles, paragraphs) in a very weird font that does not fit the normal san-serif fonts that most websites use. This was happening to me on iTunes as well on the iTunes store for song titles, album, and artist names. I recently updated to the most recent version of iTunes and i no longer have the problem there. I have tried the same websites I have problems with in IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari and they all display the same weird font. I've tried identifying the font on font identifying sites with no help there.

Here is some examples of the font on sites I've seen it:[image]

The Example to the bottom left is a closeup of the font if that helps.

I just want my computer to display font originally like it did before i downloaded so many fonts.

Let me know if anything else needs explained, thanks!

Comment: This is a long shot, and not an answer (I can't comment because of reputation): Maybe you accidentally replaced helvica/whatever fonts are not being displayed properly with different font of the same name, or maybe even deleted them.

Comment: Could be, were would I check that? Or were would I have gone to have done that?

Comment: First check what fonts aren't being displayed properly by using firebug or by looking at the source code and then compare the ones you see with the originals (you can google them or see [this list of fonts that come with windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/product.aspx?pid=161) (altho they may not come with windows 7). If I'm right you should find they don't look the same.
Either that or simply [restore Windows 7 default fonts](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-to-restore-windows-7-default-fonts/73a8eb3e-3189-4514-b87c-18fcdca4fe26)

Comment: Perform a fresh installation of all the browsers. That could help.

Comment: I restored my fonts, didn't work. All my browsers have been updated, didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran thorugh all my fonts in photoshop to comapre to the font I posted above. The font was helvetica. I found it under: Control Panel>Appearance and Personalization>Fonts>Helvetica and deleted it. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

If the  first w7 install was on a hd screen, it's possible that the rendering of bitmap fonts is corrupted. 
Try to find in your key register all instances of fonts keys ending in .fon (such as COURF.FON or SERRIFF.FON)in the following location

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]

and replace the last F in the body by a E:

> SERRIFF.FON-->SERRIFE.FON COURF.FON-->COURE.FON

or you can download the corresponding Mr FIXit from MS http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9818337

Doing this tells your machine to go back using a version of these fonts readable at lower dpi.

If you want all the petty details read this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2396756

Comment: I've tried the "Restore default font settings" with no avail. I do have the Trebuchet MS font family.

Comment: Ok, did you have a high res monitor the first time you've installed w7 ?

Comment: It's on a Dell XPS 1640. I got the 16-inch RGB LED seamless display: http://www.dell.com/us/p/studio-xps-1647/pd

Comment: @seth urquhart See my answer edited

Comment: I can't find SERRIFF anything under the location you specified.

Comment: did you try to run the FIXit patch from MS ? (link in answer)

Comment: Yes, that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-font-family-style/aabledekpjmoghdjnpnhfkfpmjifklpb/related

Install this extension in Chrome. worked for me :)

Comment: Please add an explanation of how the link answers the question. In particular, it would be helpful to give the name of the software that you're recommending the asker to use.